# Background EditText and ImageView are black?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a custom border to LinearLayout, to do it I'm using `shape` . The problem is when I set `@drawable/custom_linear_border` all EditText has background black. This problem occur with Android 2.3 because superior this problem does not occur.

How could I solve it ?

[image]

**custom_linear_border**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

**LinearLayout**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_linearlayout_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_login"
            />

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:background="#00000000"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Use this drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```